# How to fix " Cannot convert object to a function: [type=NULL; target=CLOSXP, SPECIALSXP, or BUILTINSXP]?"

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to integrate two R function to rcpp. My code is in rcpp and I need to include two R functions from "genlasso" package.

In particular, my code is the following :

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include<RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List Rcpp_fusedlasso1d(NumericVector y, NumericMatrix X){

  // Obtaining namespace of Genlasso package
  Environment pkg = Environment::namespace_env("genlasso");

  // Picking up fusedlasso1d function from genlassopackage
  Function f = pkg["fusedlasso1d"];
  List fs = f(y,Named("X",X));
  return fs;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]

List Rcpp_coef(List fs,double lambda2){

  Environment pkg = Environment::namespace_env("genlasso");
  Function g = pkg["coef"];
  return  g(fs,Named("lambda",lambda2));
}

/*** R
n = 100
i = 1:n
y = (i > 20 & i < 30) + 5*(i > 50 & i < 70) +rnorm(n, sd=0.1)
p=3
X = matrix(rnorm(n*p),nrow=n)
fs<-Rcpp_fusedlasso1d(y,X)
Rcpp_coef(fs,0.2)
*/
```

I tried different variants to overcome the problem but useless, and I always get the following error " Cannot convert object to a function: [type=NULL; target=CLOSXP, SPECIALSXP, or BUILTINSXP]".
P.S. The type of output of "coef" function in R is "list".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried an intermediate variable of type `Rcpp::List` like in your first function? Have you tried getting the `coef.genlasso` function instead of `coef`?

Comment: It worked with `coef.genlasso`. Thank you.

Comment: Great. How about adding it as a self-answer?